# Java processors - what to choose?

Tags: jvm, processors

any suggestion what kind of Java processor to choose for studying and learning purposes? 
I have read something about picoJava and its speed. DO you think it can be used for learning and practicing Java for processors?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me if you are asking about learning the Java programming language, i.e., software, or learning about the processor, i.e., hardware, which executes instructions built in a programming language.

The Java programming language is available on many different platforms (including native processors like picoJava) via the Java virtual machine (JVM). If you're interested in learning the Java programming language, choose a JVM for your favorite OS; most are free, they perform well, and have lots of good documentation and samples. For example, try downloading the Java 7 SDK from Oracle - you'll be able to write simple programs, compile them, and run them on a JVM, on your existing platform.

If you are interested in learning about processors, there are a number of simple processors available, including some specifically tailored for students at a modest cost. You can also study the processor on your own platform - some make documentation generally available, though it's generally not as accessible as programming language documentation, unless it's tailored for students, e.g., [A Simple and Affordable TTL Processor for the Classroom](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1595&context=compsci), or a [programmable interrupt controller](http://www.technologystudent.com/pics/picgen1.html).

You can also study the Java byte-code instruction set, i.e., the [instruction set of the Java virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).

You can, of course, learn the Java programming language, Java byte-code, and general processor principles at the same time, but you may find it easier to tackle these topics separately; each is vast.

Comment: ok, thank you. Can you please tell me name of some specifically tailered processors for students for good price? I would like to try it. I know Java language a little bit, so I think its time to try it work with hardware. Thank you

Comment: I've added a couple of links to student-focused processors which tend to be simple. If these seem too basic and you don't require the physical hardware, a good option is using BCEL or other byte-code generator libraries which will give a deeper understanding of JVM. Good luck and have fun!